# Ending a two handed game

Tags: canasta

It’s my turn. It is a two handed game of Canasta.

I have three cards left in my hand. There is only one card left in the Stock pile. Can I pick up the one card and play my hand?

Comment: That's three questions.  Please ask one at a time.

Comment: While you have narrowed it down to a single question I still don't think it is clear what you are asking.

Comment: Part of the confusion may come from the fact that you are referring to the game as a "two handed game", which is not terminology I am familiar with. It generally would just be called a "two player game" rather than a "two handed game".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in two-player Canasta, when there is only 1 card remaining in the stock, you can draw that 1 card and treat that as your normal draw for the turn.

From [the rules](https://www.pagat.com/rummy/canasta.html#two):

> In two-player canasta, a situation can be reached where there is only one card remaining in the stock. In this case, the player who draws it is considered to have made a complete draw and must complete that turn as though two cards had been drawn.

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you for clarifying that for me Gendolkari

Comment: @Ka7hryn0611 You're welcome! The best way to thank someone on this site is to upvote the answer and/or accept it as correct by clicking the check mark.